# open failed: ENOENT Android R

Tags: java, android, uri, ucrop

> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Already added manifests, Because Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated on Android R.if I change that to getExternalFilesDir() the path is going to the app directory, not to storage

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Android Q Below working fine but Android R got the ENOENT error

```
    protected Uri getImageFile()
    {

        String imagePathStr = IMAGE_FOLDER;
        File path = new File(imagePathStr);
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        String finalPhotoName = "IMG" +
                (withTimeStamp ? "_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())) :  "")
                + ".png";
        // long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // String photoName = imageName + "_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date(currentTimeMillis)) + ".jpg";
        File photo = new File(path, finalPhotoName);

        return Uri.fromFile(photo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the string of the IMAGE_FOLDER

try to use

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```